# Retrieving last items from an uncompleted (never completing observable) observable

Tags: rx-java

So, I have an Observable that supplies params based on UI interactions. I want the extract the last supplied params from the observable. Is there a concise way to do it regarding that the observable never ends (at least not until it has subscribers)?

I have tried different stuff resulting in execution blocking and waiting for Observable to be completed (which is not going to happen).

Consider that:

```
Integer last = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onNext(1);
        subscriber.onNext(2);
        subscriber.onNext(3);
    }
}).toBlocking().last();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) is what you're looking for. Here is the usage example:

```
private final BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.create(0);

private Observable<Integer> getUiElementValueAsObservable() {
    return subject;
}

private void notifyUiElementValueChanged(final Integer value) {
    subject.onNext(value);
}

private void performActionWithLastUiElementValue() {
    getUiElementValueAsObservable().first().subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Integer integer) {
            System.out.println("Current value " + integer);
        }
    });
}

private void run() {
    // prints "Current value 0"
    performActionWithLastUiElementValue();

    notifyUiElementValueChanged(1);
    notifyUiElementValueChanged(2);
    notifyUiElementValueChanged(3);

    // prints "Current value 3"
    performActionWithLastUiElementValue();
}
```